# VSCode language extension: can a language be embedded into another through code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, vscode-extensions

The extension adds support for Renpy language, a language very similar to Python. In this language, it's possible to embed Python code in [different ways](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/python.html).

#### Single line statement:

```
define e = Character("Eileen", who_color="#c8ffc8")
default sidebar = False
$ sampleFunction("Eileen", 1.0)
```

To embed python inside single-line statements, I use the following [TextMate Grammar](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) pattern:

```json
        {
          "comment": "Match begin and end of python one line statements",
          "name": "meta.embedded.python.line",
          "begin": "(?<=(\\$|define|default)\\s)",
          "end": "\\R$",
          "patterns": [{ "include": "source.python" }]
        }
```

In this case, I can know when a statement ends.

#### Python block:

```
python:
    def foo():
        return "bar"
```

These blocks can be nested within other language blocks, for example:

```
init:
    image movie = Movie()

    python:
        povname = ""
        pov = DynamicCharacter("povname", color=(255, 0, 0, 255))

    $ ectc = Character('Eileen', color=(200, 255, 200, 255))
```

In the case of the block, since it's delimited by indentation, I can't determine where it ends. If these blocks couldn't be nested, I could capture the end with a regular expression, e.g. `^(?=\S)`, since it can be nested I can't detect when it ends.

I tried to add the TextMate scope `source.python` via the [SemanticTokenProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#semantic-token-provider), but it seems that it's not possible to add a `textmate scope` using the [SemanticTokensBuilder](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SemanticTokensBuilder). Also tried with TextMate patterns but have not succeeded.

I would like to find a way to make the contents of Python blocks have the `source.python` TextMate scope, regardless of whether it's nested or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always a line after the block that has the same indent as the word `python:` you could try

```
{
  "begin": "^(\\s*)(python:)",
  "end": "^\\1(?=\S)",
  "beginCaptures": { "2": { "name": "keyword.other" } },
  "patterns": [{ "include": "source.python" }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's work. If I also add `|^(?=\\S)` to `end`, it works in the case there isn't a line with the same indentation after the block. `"end": "^\\1(?=\\S)|^(?=\\S)"`.

Comment: @DanielLuque I don't know how to capture the python block if it is the last part of the file

Comment: Don't worry, with your solution it's possible to capture it in all cases. I've tested and it works as expected. Thanks.